# Aggregate tags in MySQL, De-normalized result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table result as shown

```
select id, tagid from mytable

id  tagid
-------------
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   b
2   c
```

I want an sql command which shows result as

```
id     tagids
1       a,b
2       a,b,c
```

Comment: Read up on group_concat https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, I was not knowing such aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(tagid) AS tagids
from mytable
GROUP BY tagid
```